# LEFT OUTER JOIN with 'field IS NULL' in WHERE works as INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, outer-join

Today I've faced some unexplainable (for me) behavior in PostgreSQL — `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does not return records for main table (with nulls for joined one fields) in case the joined table fields are used in `WHERE` expression.

To make it easier to grasp the case details, I'll provide an example. So, let's say we have 2 tables: `item` with some goods, and `price`, referring `item`, with prices for the goods in different years:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE price(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT goods_fk FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item(id)
);
```

The table `item` has 2 records (TV set and VCR items), and the table `price` has 3 records, a price for TV set in years 2000 and 2010, and a price for VCR for year 2000 only:

```sql
INSERT INTO item(id, name)
VALUES
       (1, 'TV set'),
       (2, 'VCR');

INSERT INTO price(id, item_id, year, value)
VALUES
       (1, 1, 2000, 290),
       (2, 1, 2010, 270),
       (3, 2, 2000, 770);
       -- no price of VCR for 2010
```

Now let's make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query, to get prices for all items for year 2010:

```sql
SELECT
    i.*,
    p.year,
    p.value
FROM item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN price p ON i.id = p.item_id
WHERE p.year = 2010 OR p.year IS NULL;
```

For some reason, this query will return a results only for TV set, which has a price for this year. Record for VCR is absent in results:

```
 id |  name  | year | value 
----+--------+------+-------
  1 | TV set | 2010 |   270
(1 row)
```

After some experimenting, I've found a way to make the query to return results I need (all records for `item` table, with nulls in the fields of joined table in case there are no mathing records for the year. It was achieved by moving year filtering into a `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    p.year,
    p.value
FROM item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM price
    WHERE year = 2010 -- <= here I filter a year
) p ON i.id = p.item_id;
```

And now the result is:

```
 id |  name  | year | value 
----+--------+------+-------
  1 | TV set | 2010 |   270
  2 | VCR    |      |      
(2 rows)
```

*My main question is* — why the first query (with year filtering in `WHERE`) does not work as expected, and turns instead into something like `INNER JOIN`?

I'm severely blocked by this issue on my current project, so I'll be thankful about tips/hints on the next related questions too:

1. Are there any other options to achieve the proper results?
2. ... especially — easily translatable to Django's ORM queryset?

Upd: @astentx suggested to move filtering condition directly into `JOIN` (and it works too):

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    p.year,
    p.value
FROM item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN price p 
    ON  
        i.id = p.item_id 
    AND p.year = 2010;
```

Though, the same as my first solution, I don't see how to express it in terms of Django ORM querysets. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Row for the VCR is joined by `left join`, and `year` is not null or 2010 for it. That's why it gets filtered out. You may move your `where` condition for the year (without`is null`) to the `join` condition to achieve what you want (without subquery)

Comment: @astentx yep, it works. Though, the same as my first solution, I don't see how could I express it with Django querysets (but will work on it, thank you!)

Comment: @astentx and also, I guess my main question if full covered by your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Django. You have to research how to put custom join condition with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first query does not work as expected because expectation is wrong. It does not work as INNER JOIN as well. The query returns a record for VCR only if there is no price for VCR at all.

Comment: As far as I understand you need to return prices for items by years even there is no item's price for some year - in this case the price is unknown (NULL). Do you have some timeline table with the list of years or could you generate this list on the fly? If yes, you could LEFT JOIN the price table with cartesian product of item table and years table/list by item_id and year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    y.year,
    p.value
FROM item i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2010 AS year) y -- here could be a table
LEFT OUTER JOIN price p 
    ON (p.item_id = i.id
        AND p.year = y.year);
```